# How to get color data of lighting for materials?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm trying to make a cell-shaded material in EEVEE using a color texture plugged into an emission shader. However, I'd like the color of the texture to react to the color of the light it is around. How can I accomplish this? I assume I'll need to convert a shader to RGB and overlay it with the texture, but I'm unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but if you want colored light to apply in a "toon" fashion, you could try something like this.

In the example below, I have a single red light to the side.

[image: Toon1]

And in this picture, I un-hid a green light above and to the right as well.

[image: Toon2]

If you want to take it one step further and make the toon shadows darker and more apparent, you can turn it back into an RGB, and then multiply it with the values from your "toon shadows" ColorRamp.

[image: Toon3]

Or if you want really dark, vibrant colors from the lights (this will heavily wash out the original texture's color, but can be slightly overcome by turning up the emission strength from your image texture), you can make it a Diffuse Shader again:

[image: Toon4]

Let me know if this works.